# Nb_words code counting partial matches in R

Tags: r

before I get started, I would like you to know that I am completely new to coding in R. For a group assignment our professor set up a database by scraping data from Amazon. Within the database, which is called 'dat', there is a column named 'product_name'. We were given a set group of utilitarian words. I think you can guess where this is going. Within the column 'product_name' we have to find for each product name whether any of the utilitarian words appeared. If yes, how many times. We were given the following code by our professor to use for this assignment:

```
nb_words <- function(lexicon,corpus){
  rowSums(sapply(lexicon, function(x) grepl(x, corpus)))
}
```

after which i created the following codes:

```
uti_words <-c("additives","antioxidant","artificial", "busy", "calcium","calories", "carb", "carbohydrates", "chemicals", "cholesterol", "convenient", "dense", "diet", "fast")

sentences <- (dat$product_name)     

nb_words (lexicon=uti_words,corpus=sentences)
```

when i run nb_words, however, I noticed something went wrong. A sentence contained the word 'breakfast'. My code counted this as a match because the word 'fast' from 'uti_words' matched with it. I don't want this to happen, does anyone know how to make it so that I only get exact matches and no partial matches?

Answer (score 0):

We may have to add word boundary (`\\b`) to avoid partial matches

```
uti_words <- paste0("\\b", trimws(uti_words), "\\b")
```

---

Or another option is to change the `grepl` part of the code with `fixed = TRUE`

```
nb_words <- function(lexicon,corpus){
  rowSums(sapply(lexicon, function(x) grepl(x, corpus, fixed = TRUE)))
}
```

Comment: Hey thank you for helping! I've got one question though:

when i ran the word boundary, it worked. However, there might be one problem. When a utilitarian word is at the beginning of a sentence, it appears to not register that word. Could it be because there is a space before 'uti_words' in the code?

Comment: @Knawhledge could be.  You can use `trimws` to remove the leading/lagging spaces as in the update